# how to reduce running time in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, networking, operating-system

I have the following program which generates 100 million mac's and append it into the list.

But the 100 million mac's generation and insertion itself takes ~7 Minutes in python???

```
    import datetime
    def mac_gen():
    hex_byte1=0
    hex_byte2=0
    hex_byte3=0
    hex_byte4=0
    hex_byte5=0
    hex_byte6=0
    hex_byte7=0
    hex_byte8=0
    hex_byte9=0
    hex_byte10=0
    hex_byte11=0
    hex_byte12=0
    total_mac = 0
    for hex_byte_12 in range(0,16):
        for hex_byte11 in range(0,16):
            for hex_byte10 in range(0,16):
                for hex_byte9 in range(0,16):
                    for hex_byte8 in range(0,16):
                        for hex_byte7 in range(0,16):
                            for hex_byte6 in range(0,16):
                                for hex_byte5 in range(0,16):
                                    for hex_byte4 in range(0,16):
                                        for hex_byte3 in range(0,16):
                                            for hex_byte2 in range(0,16):
                                                for hex_byte1 in range(0,16):
                                                    total_mac +=1;
                                                    if total_mac > number_of_mac_to_print:
                                                       return
                                                    mac_list.append("%X%X:%X%X:%X%X:%X%X:%X%X:%X%X" %(hex_byte_12,hex_byte11,hex_byte10,hex_byte9,hex_byte8,hex_byte7,hex_byte6,hex_byte5,hex_byte4,hex_byte3,hex_byte2,hex_byte1))

mac_list=list()
number_of_mac_to_print = 100000000
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
mac_gen()
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
print(len(mac_list))
```

### Output:

2018-03-09 07:15:41.650460  <--- time stamp before calling mac_gen method

2018-03-09 07:22:33.902744  <--- time stamp after calling mac_gen method

100000000 . <---- total entries. 100 million

so question is:

1. how to reduce the running time from 7 minutes to lowest as possible in python?
2. if the same problem i am solving in C or C plus plus give please give me generrfic solution for that as well?
3. when running the same code for 1 Billion mac it is terminating automatically i belive. and taking much more time. how to achive for 1 Billion mac generation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: look into `itertools.product`

Comment: thanks. let me have a look. :-)

Comment: actually there's much better to do.

Comment: try to profile the time on which part of the code spend most of the time and then find a way to reduce the computational time on that crucial part only.

Comment: To me, it's hard to understand the overall requirement, why you'd want to list all possible MAC addresses in a file. It's like listing all the integers from 0 to 100 millions to a file - why would someone want to do that? What do you want to do with that file that can't be better done algorithmically?

Comment: i am trying to simulate the mac-table(i.e. in networks it stores all the mac address of the received packets during learning time).
so once the mac table(in our case list/other data structure like hash) populated then whenever new packet comes with this already
learned mac address then lookup happens and returns the index from this list/hash.

so that is the reason i am trying to populate my list(in future hash) with 100 million mac. so in future if i learn packet
with this mac address then i will do lookup and return index. that is the whole idea

Comment: @Mr.SelvaKumar Ok, got it. But I'd treat the mac addresses in the mac-table not as strings, but as 48-bit numbers (if the rest of your software allows you to do so). Then instead of initializing the mac table from a text file, you could fill it from a simple loop.

Comment: Rather than creating a list, populate the real table you are going to create. As others have said, there's no point putting the addresses in the list in string form, using a more compact form is one of several optimisations your hash table will have to do to be faster than the list.

Answer (score 5):

The long running times you're experiencing are quite likely to result from memory being paged out to your hard drive in order to make room for the addition of new items to `mac_list`.

I can't think of any good reason why you would need to store all these MACs in memory. They're numbered consecutively, so you can easily generate them on the fly:

```
gen_mac = lambda n: ":".join([("%012X" % n)[i:i+2] for i in range(0,12,2)])
```

Then instead of fetching items from `mac_list`, just use this function instead. In other words, replace

```
m = mac_list[12345678]
```

with

```
m = gen_mac(12345678)
```

Comment: the reason for 100 million mac is:   i am trying to simulate the mac-table(i.e. in networks it stores all the mac address of the received packets during learning time).
so once the mac table(in our case list/other data structure like hash) populated then whenever new packet comes with this already
learned mac address then lookup happens and returns the index from this list/hash.

so that is the reason i am trying to populate my list(in future hash) with 100 million mac. so in future if i learn packet
with this mac address then i will do lookup and return index. that is the whole idea

Comment: @Mr.SelvaKumar What do you mean by "return index"? Can't you just write a function to convert a MAC into an integer? How about `mac_2_int = lambda m: int(m.replace(":",""),16)`?

Comment: actual idea is put 100 million entries into hash instead of list. Whenever the lookup happens for any one entry in this 100 million hash table I plan to return the location/index where this mac entry stored.is your idea of converting into integer will help?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but if the index of `00:00:00:00:00:01` is 1 and the index of `00:00:00:00:00:FF` is 255, then all you need is a function that converts MACs into integers, which I have already given you (`mac_2_int = lambda m: int(m.replace(":",""),16)`).

Comment: if i convert into integer index from MAC address then index ranges from 1 to 170859375 (00:00:00:00:00:01 to 00:00:0F:FF:FF:FF). i.e 15 power 7. 100 million.  what you think about collion handling and memory point of view. too much memory utilisation and too much running time to generate this much entry know? so do you think lookup also takes more time?

Comment: @Mr.SelvaKumar I'm sorry, but now I really have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The following code takes 3:20 on my laptop

```
mac_list=list()
for i in range(0, 100000000):
    strHex = hex(i)[2:].rjust(12, '0')
    mac_list.append(strHex[0:2] + ":"+strHex[2:4] + ":"+strHex[4:6] + ":"+strHex[6:8] + ":"+strHex[8:10] + ":"+strHex[10:12])
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do that ? All `12` digit hex numbers would fill up the largest supercomputer (`281474976710656` values). Actually, all first `100000000` addresses have a zero for the first five digits (as `16^7 = 268435456`).

Do you really need to store all these addresses ? If yes, I would recommend to use a single `range(100000000)` and leave the values as integers, only convert to hex when needed. This will spare a lot of space.

If not possible, it is probably more efficient to work with a string of `12` hex characters that you increment yourself rather than using a costly formatting operation.

And please, don't store those `500000000` `':'` useless separators.

Comment: the reason for 100 million mac is: i am trying to simulate the mac-table(i.e. in networks it stores all the mac address of the received packets during learning time). so once the mac table(in our case list/other data structure like hash) populated then whenever new packet comes with this already learned mac address then lookup happens and returns the index from this list/hash. so that is the reason i am trying to populate my list(in future hash) with 100 million mac. so in future if i learn packet with this mac address then i will do lookup and return index. that is the whole idea

Comment: @Mr.SelvaKumar: then you will certainly not store them in a list.